# Semantic error in designing ontology in protege

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

Using protege 5.0, I have class A,B and C such that

B is subclass A ,

C is subclass of B.

I define object property P1 and P2 such that

P2 is subproperty of P1.

Domain of P1 is C

Range Of P1 is A,

Domain of P2 is C,

Range of P2 is B.

Having instances a,b and c for classes A,B and C, suppose

c P2 b

Running the reasoner I expect It showed c P1 a but surprisingly it showed c P1 b !

How should I change my design that reasoner show c P1 a ?

Comment: Please format the axiom line by line first. It's hard to read it inline.

Comment: And why do you expect that `c P1 a` given that you have only `c P2 b` and `P2 subPropertyOf P1`.

Comment: You're right! The concept of my knowledge is such that I expect it showed `c P1 a`. What axiom should I add for reasoning and showing `c P1 a` ?

Comment: Your last example would work if `hasFather` is transitive and `hasFather subPropertyOf hasAncestor` . But I still don't see a relationship to your original question. I still don't see how your expected axioms should be inferred. I mean, based on which closure? Can you clarify that?

Comment: My real axioms are `Property: RHasDatgah isSuperPropertyOf RHasAvaz` and `Class: Dastghah isSuperClassOf Avaz` and `Class: Avaz isSuperClassOf Radif`. So suppose dastgah, avaz and radif are instances of Dastgah, Avaz and Radif. Suppose `avaz AHasDastgah dastgah` and `radif RHasAvaz avaz`, I want reasoner shows `radif RHasDastgah dastgah`.

Comment: I added superPropertyOf(Chain): `RHasAvaz o AHasdastgah subPropertyOf RHasDastgah` and reasoner successfully shows `radif RHasDastgah dastgah` but is still showing `radif RHasdastgah avaz`, How can I get rid of this `radif RHasdastgah avaz`?

Comment: Impossible as long as you have the axiom `Property: RHasDatgah isSuperPropertyOf RHasAvaz`. It's quite obvious that given `radif RHasAvaz avaz` a reasoner will infer `radif RHasdastgah avaz`, isn't it? If you remove the subPropertyOf axiom, the inferred fact will disappear, but I don't know if that's what you want. Note, that **reasoning in OWL is monotonic**, i.e. adding more information cannot retract any existing assertions or axioms

Answer (score 0):

From your axioms, there is no relation that can be inferred between distinct instances of A; a and b are in no way connected, so the reasoner will not infer the axiom you expect. the fact that b is inferred to me an instance of A does not imply that the same axioms that involve b are also inferrable for a.

As far as I can tell, this could only happen if a and b are declared to be sameAs each other, or if the cardinality of A can be inferred to be 1 - which means that any instance of A is sameAs all other instances of A. But I don't believe this is what you want to achieve.